# Preimage attack on cbc-mac with constant key

Tags: hash, cbc-mac

Is a hash function created by using CBC-MAC with one public key that does not change secure against preimage attacks? If not, how could you exploit this to find a single block message that hashes to a given digest?

Comment: A super obvious hint: try decrypting the digest.

Comment: Okay so I get that I can decrypt the digest since the key is public, but wont the plaintext still be XOR'ed with the IV since its CBC-MAC? Or am I missing something

Comment: Sure it's xor'd with the IV, but that's just 1 block, and nothing else.

Comment: So I can use the digest from the first encryption operation and xor it with the decrypted digest from the second message in order to find message block 2? But it wont be possible to find message block 1? Is this understanding correct? How would you know what the previous block digest would be for a randomly given digest?

Comment: m = IV xor Dec(<digest>); It's night in my timezone, I'm off to bed. Keep digesting knowledge.

Comment: That makes sense, but how would the attacker have the IV in order to do that calculation? I thought it was secret?

Comment: How do you compute a public hash function on an input of your choice, if it has a secret IV?  It would be rather difficult to use SHA-256 if it had a secret IV, for example!

Comment: CBC-MAC uses an all-zero IV.